# java.net.UnknownHostException: redisson-netty-2-6 ERROR DNSMonitor

Tags: redis, netty, redisson

`redissonClient.getNodesGroup().pingAll()`

Returning true but still getting the exception ->

> [10-09-2018 21:00:05.337] [redisson-netty-2-6]
>
> [ERROR]
> DNSMonitor$1$1:98 cr_id= parent_reqid= reqid=
>
> - Unable to resolve
>   xxxx.redis.cache.windows.net java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to
>   resolve 'xxxx.redis.cache.windows.net' after 4 queries

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 2.15.1 / 3.10.1 versions